# Does ArcMap 10 have a command line switch that is roughly equivalent to Visual Studio's /SafeMode?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

Anytime I had an  ArcMap 9.x related incident open with ESRI, they always had me do the usual steps of uninstalling extensions and tools, renaming the ESRI profile folder to ESRI_old, and renaming the ESRI registry key under HKCU to ESRI_old.

I am unable to find a list of arcmap.exe command line switches, but I feel like a [/SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) type of switch would really speed up troubleshooting.  The only command line switch I know of is `/log`.

Does anyone know of a [/SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) equivalent or have a link to arcmap.exe command line switches?

Comment: The only thing I have ever known about for arcmap is to rename normal.mxt.

Comment: http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2007/02/esri-arcgis-92-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: yes need to update that it for ArcGIS 10 for Windows 7. I know more tips and tricks now but involves items that 'general users' might not understand and then really mess up their system. A Safe Mode for ESRI ArcGIS would be nice (load no extensions 3-party stuff)

Comment: the issue with the safe mode idea is that many of the 3rd Party extensions actually change the core ArcGIS libraries. ERMapper Plugin for ArcGIS is just one example. This one changes the raster handling so that all rasters are dependant on the ER mapper plugin. Hard to then strip that out for a safe mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcMap does not have such a command line switch.  There are very few command line switches for ArcMap.  I can think of only /print in addition to /log and it gets little use because there better ways to automate printing than the switch.